# Pandas - replacing NaN values using values from other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've started to work with pandas recently and I am trying to do some simple cleaning in data. So far I've learned that there are a lot of one-liners when using pandas. So I am looking also for one in my case. I have `DataFrame` like this:

```
    C0          C1    C2         C3        C4
    3789507     2010   NaN        NaN        NaN  
    3789508      NaN   NaN       2010        NaN  
    3789509      NaN   NaN       2016        NaN  
    3789510      NaN  2014        NaN        NaN
    3789511      NaN   NaN        NaN      2014
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
C0          C1
3789507     2010
3789508     2010
3789509     2016
3789510     2014
3789511     2014
```

What I am doing now is simply:

```
k = df.C1.isnull()
df.C1[k] = df.C2[k]
k = df.C1.isnull()
df.C1[k] = df.C3[k]
k = df.C1.isnull()
df.C1[k] = df.C4[k]
```

It is working, but is not the nicest solution. What if I'll ave 100 of columns? Is loop here only solution?

Just in case my for loop looks like this:

```
for i in range(2,len(df.columns)):
    k = df.C1.isnull()
    df.C1[k] = df.ix[:,i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has some methods to backfill and forwardfill missing values, so you can do:

```
df['C1'] = df.bfill(axis='columns')['C1']

df
Out[10]: 
        C0      C1      C2      C3      C4
0  3789507  2010.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1  3789508  2010.0     NaN  2010.0     NaN
2  3789509  2016.0     NaN  2016.0     NaN
3  3789510  2014.0  2014.0     NaN     NaN
4  3789511  2014.0     NaN     NaN  2014.0
```

This works for your simple example data but in a real dataset you may have to restrict the columns that are being backfilled over like:

```
fill_cols = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']
df['C1'] = df[fill_cols].bfill(axis='columns')['C1']
```

Comment: Just one question - if it's not a big trouble, can you please explain how does it actually work? Should I read it from the back? I mean this real life case with selected columns.

Comment: OK, so look at the row where `C4` has a value, but the other columns are all missing. `df.bfill(axis='columns')` creates a new dataframe where every missing value to the left of `C4` in that row gets the value from `C4`. The valid value in `C4` is 'backfilled' into all the missing columns. Then we just copy the backfilled C1 column into the original dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much - now I get it.